# How do I display =filter() results as a comma separated list?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet that I am using the filter formula to find and display multiple values. This works great for displaying the results in a vertical column, where the values are pasted down in the column below the formula.

However, I would like to display the results in a comma separated list in one cell (or alternatively, pasted horizontally). Is there an alternate formula I should be using, or some formula to transpose the vertical results?

Answer (score 2):

If it's just a single column of results, you could use JOIN:

```
=JOIN(",",FILTER(...))
```

Alternatively, You could also use

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(...))
```